# Is it required to explicitly define the type of value or parameter in Powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell

I am having difficulty finding the answer to this question (possibly because I am wording it incorrectly). I am working on a Powershell script to create a GUI via a form object. I am setting parameters like StartPosition and AutoScaleMode.

My question is relating to the values that I set for these parameters. Here are some examples:

```
$form.AutoScaleMode = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode]::Font
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$form.SizeGripStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle]::Hide
$label.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]46,[System.Int32]282))
```

Are the following formattings also valid for these same parameters?

```
$form.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60,300)
```

I am asking this because I dislike how cluttered the code looks compared to simply typing in the desired value (I used a Powershell GUI builder and it hardcoded the values, when I wrote my script originally I only used the values alone). It makes it more difficult to read for my team. Also, if the formatting is valid, does it matter if I use single or double quotes for things like 'Font' or 'Fixed3D'?

Let me know if any clarification is needed, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the property type, if the type can be casted from the value you're giving then the answer is yes, without a problem. For the [`Enums`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-7.0), they can be casted from a string without a problem. For example, for [`AutoScaleMode` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), this works:

```bash
[System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode] 'Font'
```

So from there you can assume that this will also work:

```bash
[System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{ AutoScale = 'Font' }
```

For the [`Point` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-7.0) you can take a similar approach:

```bash
[System.Drawing.Point] '200, 200'
```

Knowing that the type can be instantiated from a string in that format then you can assume that the following will work:

```bash
[System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{ Location = '200, 200' }
```